# I want to POST/PATCH Map<String,List<int>> and also ImageFile using Dio in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to send this JSON file to API -

```
 {
            "speciality": [7,2]
        }
```

My Workings:

```
    class Doctor {
          dynamic specialities;
        
          Doctor({
            this.specialities,
          });
        
          Map<String,dynamic>toJson()=>{
            "speciality": List<dynamic>.from(specialities.map((x) => x)),
         };
        }
```

So when I used http.patch it worked fine (code below). My question is how to do the same thing using Dio package because I am working with MuiltipartFile.

```
response = await http.patch(
      Uri.encodeFull(fullUrl),
      body: jsonEncode(doctor.toJson()),//jsonEncode(data),
      headers: {
       'Content-type' : 'application/json',
       'Accept' : 'application/json',
       'Authorization' : 'Token $token',
     },
    );
```

I tried using Dio code(below), I got no error in the console but it is not patching successfully.

```
updateDoctorInformation(Doctor doctor,token) async{
    Dio dio = new Dio();
            var formData = FormData();
            formData = FormData.fromMap(doctor.toJson());
            
            Response response = await dio.patch(
                      Uri.encodeFull(fullUrl),
                      data: formData,
                      options: Options(
                        followRedirects: false,
                        validateStatus: (status) {
                          return status < 500;
                        },
                        headers: {
                          'Content-type' : 'multipart/form-data',
                          'Accept' : '*/*',
                          'Authorization' : 'Token $token',
                        },
                      )).catchError((onError){
                    print(onError.toString());
                  }).whenComplete(() => print("completed"));
                  print(response.data);
                  return response;
}
```

I Need the Dio code correction. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way that is adding separately.

```
if(doctor.specialities !=null){
        for(int i=0;i<doctor.specialities.length;i++){
          formData.fields.add(
              MapEntry("speciality",doctor.specialities[i].toString())
          );
        }
      }
```

Still, I am seeking for a better solution like using toJson above